# How to master automated time series parameter tuning using tidymodels?

Tags: r, tidyverse, resampling, hyperparameters, tidymodels

as I come from a classical time series analysis approach, I am still kinda new to parameter tuning. As tuning all local models (couple of hundreds of time series for product demand in my case) turns out to be not even near scalability, I want to analyze first the effect of tuning time series with low accuracy values, to evaluate the trade-off between scalability and accuracy, to see if tuning is justified for a particular time series issue.
When I run the code below, it seems like I didn't properly specify the ranges for the regular grid. I think so, because it seems odd, to retrieve only three combinations for a tree value with range from 50 to 2000. Is this standard behavior? Does changing the levels argument help in this case somehow? It didn't change anything in my case. Also, is there a way to retrieve the optimal number of folds for resampling, rather than guessing it? I hope for some advise or useful examples.

Thanks in advance!

```
# data and libs
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lubridate))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(timetk))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidymodels))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(modeltime))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tictoc))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(readxl))

dates <- ymd("2016-01-01")+ months(0:59)
fake_values <-c(296,325,339,812,723,310,842,500,555,260,243,306,204,330,467,713,1054,827,75,437 ,558,222,350,139,306,395,472,741,1020,903,837,738,676,506,199,219,342,406,417 ,977,1503,117,942,843,716,378,267,392,329,369,536,1168,1260,1066,949,906,1744,2495,418,447)
df <- bind_cols(fake_values, dates) %>%
    rename(c(y = ...1, ds = ...2))



# training- and test set
data_splits <- initial_time_split(df, prop = 0.8)
data_train  <- training(data_splits)
data_test   <- testing(data_splits)

# plot cv
split_obj<- time_series_split(df, assess = "1 year", cumulative = TRUE)       
split_obj %>%
    tk_time_series_cv_plan() %>%
    plot_time_series_cv_plan(ds, y)

# Resample - CV plan
resampling_strategy <- 
    data_train %>%
    time_series_cv(
        initial = "36 months",
        assess = "12 months",
        skip = "12 months",
        cumulative = TRUE
)


# model spec
prophet_boost_model <- prophet_boost(
    mode = "regression",
    growth = "linear",
    changepoint_num =tune(),
    changepoint_range = tune(),
    trees = tune()
) %>% 
    set_engine("prophet_xgboost")

# regular grid
prophet_grid <- grid_regular(
    changepoint_num(range = c(1L, 45L)),
    changepoint_range(range = c(0.5, 0.9)),
    trees(range = c(50,2000))
    #, levels = 10
    #, size = 100
)

# recipe
basic_rec <- recipe(y ~ ds, data = data_train)

# wf
wflw_spec_tune_prophet <- workflow() %>%
    add_model(prophet_boost_model) %>%
    add_recipe(basic_rec)

# parallel proc
#cores <- parallel::detectCores(logical = FALSE)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)


# automated tuning
tic()
tune_results <-
    wflw_spec_tune_prophet %>% 
    tune_grid(
        resamples = resampling_strategy,
        grid = prophet_grid,
        metrics = metric_set(rmse, mae))
toc()
stopCluster(cl)

# save the best model
best_results <- tune_results %>%
    show_best(metric = 'rmse',n = 20)
best_results
best_results$mean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right on the money! Changing the `levels` parameter in `grid_regular()` is how you can increase the number of parameters to try within your range. Here's a few examples - hope this helps!

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip

# levels will default to 3 for each tuned paramater
grid_regular(
  trees(range = c(50, 2000)),
  mtry(range = c(1, 10))
)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   trees  mtry
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1    50     1
#> 2  1025     1
#> 3  2000     1
#> 4    50     5
#> 5  1025     5
#> 6  2000     5
#> 7    50    10
#> 8  1025    10
#> 9  2000    10

# you can also specify the number of levels!
grid_regular(
  trees(range = c(50, 2000)),
  mtry(range = c(1, 10)),
  levels = 5
)
#> # A tibble: 25 x 2
#>    trees  mtry
#>    <int> <int>
#>  1    50     1
#>  2   537     1
#>  3  1025     1
#>  4  1512     1
#>  5  2000     1
#>  6    50     3
#>  7   537     3
#>  8  1025     3
#>  9  1512     3
#> 10  2000     3
#> # ... with 15 more rows

# or, if you want to, you can specify different number
# of tuning parameters to try for each by creating a vector
grid_regular(
  trees(range = c(50, 2000)),
  mtry(range = c(1, 10)),
  levels = c(3, 2)
)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   trees  mtry
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1    50     1
#> 2  1025     1
#> 3  2000     1
#> 4    50    10
#> 5  1025    10
#> 6  2000    10
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I cannot figure out, why levels argument did not work out for me in the first place, but now it does. Maybe I was walking through too many random forests today... Your tip to use a vector for levels will definitely help speeding up the process. My next question would be, why are there so many combinations in the best model overview having exactly the same rmse. For example: changepoint_num of 21 vs. 45. Just curious, maybe will I figure it out myself